# Prove that $\mathbb{Z}+(3x)$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and there is no surjective homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}[x]\to\mathbb{Z}+(3x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I have shown that $\mathbb{Z}+(3x)$ is a subring by the subring test.

> However, is there such surjective homomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}[x]\to\mathbb{Z}+(3x)$?

If so, by the isomorphism theorem we have $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\ker{\varphi}\simeq\mathbb{Z}+(3x)$.

Comment: To define a homomorphism, you would need to say what x maps to.  Try some things out, are any of them subjective?  Something would need to map to 3x, something else would need to map to $3x^2$.  Can you use this?

Comment: @Aaron, could I make it as $\varphi(f)=f(3x)$?

Comment: that would define a homomorphism. Is it surjective? Why or why not?

Comment: @Aaron, I guess yes since it's a subring? But I found another thing: $\varphi(f)=f(3x)=3x\cdot g(x) + r$ for some $g(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x],r\in\mathbb{Z}$, then by division formula they are uniquely determined by $f$ and hence injective. $\mathbb{Z}+(3x)\simeq \mathbb{Z}[x]$ as it is a subring. Is it correct?

Comment: It being a subring isn't relevant to surjectivity.  But I do not follow your other argument.  The only thing it is showing, best I can tell is that the image of the map lies inside where you want it to lie.  But I will say, $f\mapsto f(3x)$ extends to a map from $\mathbb Q[x]$ to itself, and it is an isomorphism there.  That can be used to show that this map is injective.  Subrings are not, in general, isomorphic to the rings they are in.  For example, $\mathbb Z\subset \mathbb Z[x]$ but the two are most definitely not isomorphic.

Comment: @Aaron I am sorry that I am confused now. $\mathbb{Z}+(3x)$ isn't finitely generated as an $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra, but I don't know how to show that.

Comment: Fortunately, the problem isn't to show that it isn't finitely generated, simply that it isn't generated by a single element.

Comment: @Aaron, I am sorry that I am totally lost. Would you mind being explicit on how to prove that there is no such surjective map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no surjective homomorphism.  Suppose that $\varphi:\mathbb Z[x]\to \mathbb Z + (3x)$.  Since $\deg\varphi(f(x))=\deg(f(\varphi(x))=\deg(f(x))\deg(\varphi (x))$, if $\deg \varphi(x)>1$, then nothing in the image could be of degree $1$, and the map could not be surjective.  So $\varphi(x)=3ax+b$ for some $a, b \in \mathbb Z$. If $\varphi$ were surjective, something would have to map to $3x$, and this forces $a=\pm 1$.  By composing with the isomorphisms of $\mathbb Z[x]$ given by maps $x\mapsto x-c$ and $x\mapsto -x$, we may WLOG assume that $\varphi(x)=3x$.

The question we ask is, can we find $g(x)$ such that $\varphi(g(x))=g(3x)=3x^2$?  Working over $\mathbb Q[x]$, we see that if $g(3x)=3x^2$, then $g(x)=x^2/3\not\in \mathbb Z[x]$.  And because $\varphi$ extends to an isomorphism of $\mathbb Q[x]$, this is the only polynomial in $\mathbb Q[x]$ that would satisfy the condition.   So the map cannot be surjective.